# How to pass structure by reference with JNA

Tags: java, c++, structure, jna

I want to call this function :

```
extern "C" xxx_SERVICE_API int  initSocket(socketStruct* skStruct);
```

defined in a c++ dll.socketStruct is a structure defined below:

```
typedef struct 
{
    int a;
    int b;
} mystruct;
```

equivalent code in java is :

```
public interface MyDllClass extends Library {

    public static class MyStructure extends Structure {

        public static class ByReference extends MyStructureRef
        implements Structure.ByReference{ 


        }
        @Override
        protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {    

            return Arrays.asList(new String[]{"a","b"});
        }
        public int a;
        public int b;
    }
    //Native function
    int initSocket (MyStructure.ByReference sks); 
    MyDllClass INSTANCE = (MyDllClass)Native.loadLibrary("Mydll",  
    MyDllClass.class); 
}
```

How can i call this native fucntion with the structure by reference as parameter?
Thank you

Thank you for your answer. According with you i add a contructor to my structure:

```
public interface MyDllClass extends Library {

    public static class MyStructure extends Structure {

       public MyStructure() {

            idModule = 0;
            nbModules = 0;
            nbQueueInModule = 3;
            portList = new int[128];
            serverList = new char[128][20]; 
        }
        @Override
        protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {    

            return Arrays.asList(new String[]{"a","b","portList","serverList"});
        }
        public int a;
        public int b;
        public int[] portList;
        public char[][] serverList;
    }
    //Native function
    int initSocket (MyStructure.ByReference sks); 
    MyDllClass INSTANCE = (MyDllClass)Native.loadLibrary("Mydll",  
    MyDllClass.class); 
}
```

In the main I wrote this code :

```
MyStructure mySocket = new MyStructure();
MyDllClass.INSTANCE.initSocket(mySocket);
```

This code fail because of Null pointer exception when calling the native function. 
Do you  have an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

All JNA `Structure` parameters default to by reference (`struct*`) semantics.

When appearing as structure members, they default to by value semantics.

The `ByReference` and `ByValue` tagging interfaces are provided for use where you want the complementary behavior.  If the default behavior is what you want, you don't need the extra typing.

You should always provide a `Pointer`-based constructor to `Structure`s you define, it avoids superfluous memory allocation by JNA.